# Как поместить данный цикл в переменную?

Tags: php, переменные, циклы

Как поместить данный цикл в переменную? Выводиться, только последний час...(

```
$hhmmstart = new DateTime('00:00');
$hhmmend = new DateTime('23:59')
$proverka = array();
while($hhmmstart <= $hhmmend )
{

$proverka = $hhmmstart->format("H:i");

$hhmmstart->modify("+ $delim minutes");
}
```

Comment: @bajex, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите записать  все данные в массив, то

```
$proverka[] = $hhmmstart->format("H:i");
```

**Обновление**

Чтоб посмотреть что внутри массива

```
var_dump($proverka);
```

Можете пройти циклом массив `$proverka`

```
foreach ($proverka as $hhmm) {
     if ($hhmm == "19:30") {
            // код
     }
}
```

Comment: Выводит array просто, а возможно ли будет потом, проверку сделать, допустим на время if($proverka == 19:30) { echo "1";} else {...} типо такого?

Comment: Чтоб посмотреть что внутри массива 

var_dump($proverka);

Можете пройти циклом массив $proverka

foreach ($proverka as $hhmm) {
         If ($hhmm == "19:30") {
                // код
         }
}